# React native - How to pass data to another screen using class components

Tags: react-native, class, react-native-navigation

i want to send an ID that i get from a database to another screen and i've seen how to do it on google but people only use hook components and i'm new to react native so i don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: That (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/.) doesn't work on my code, because i'm using class components, can you help me do it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from one screen to another using navigation params. Here is example: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/.

Comment: If you are using class components, I would suggest you start using functional ones.

Comment: i understand but i have to do it with class components, also i have a button that gets a an id from a list of touchable data, and i cant make it work with the navigation.navigate('route',{paramName:value})